# Who do I change strings in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting a string from an asps page like this:

```
~/TestImages/media/9.jpg?width=443&height=388&ext=.jpg?id=92, 
~/TestImages/media/8.jpg?width=506&height=337&ext=.jpg?id=91, 
~/TestImages/media/jpeg-3.jpg?width=720&height=480&ext=.jpg?id=75, 
~/TestImages/media/4.jpg?width=725&height=483&ext=.jpg?id=77, 
~/TestImages/media/7.jpg?width=957&height=629&ext=.jpg?id=81, 
~/TestImages/media/10.jpg?width=478&height=356&ext=.jpg?id=85,
```

Each has a line break "\r\n" though..

Want to create an array with just the URL's (ie. "/TestImages/media/9.jpg").

Trying:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data){
            var str = data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,""),
                imgArray = new Array,
                tdata = str.split(",");

            // make random order
            for(var i=0; i < 13; i++){
                var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*tdata.length);
                imgArray.push(tdata.splice(randomNumber,1));
            }
            $.each(imgArray, function(i, item) {
                var tmp = "";
                tmp = item[0].match(/~(.*?)\.jpg/g, "$1");                 
                item[0] = tmp;
            });

        }
    });
```

Not having much luck changing the value inside the array..  anyone have a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to does the job:

```
var s = "~/TestImages/media/9.jpg?width=443&height=388&ext=.jpg?id=92, \
~/TestImages/media/8.jpg?width=506&height=337&ext=.jpg?id=91, \
~/TestImages/media/jpeg-3.jpg?width=720&height=480&ext=.jpg?id=75, \
~/TestImages/media/4.jpg?width=725&height=483&ext=.jpg?id=77, \
~/TestImages/media/7.jpg?width=957&height=629&ext=.jpg?id=81, \
~/TestImages/media/10.jpg?width=478&height=356&ext=.jpg?id=85";

var sa = s.split(",");
for(var i=0; i < sa.length;i++) {
  var first = sa[i].indexOf("/");
  var last  = sa[i].indexOf("?");
  sa[i] = sa[i].substring(first, last);
}

console.log(sa);
```

You can play with this code here: http://jsbin.com/ePevaWos/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = $.map(data.split(','), function(s) {
    return s.trim().split('?').shift();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4MLra/3/)

Answer (score 0):

<s>$.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data){
            var str = data.replace(/[\r\n])/g,""),//remove all line breaks
                tdata = str.split(","),
                imgArray = [];</s>

```
        $.each(tdata, function(i, item) {
            var match = item.match(/~(.*?)\.jpg/)[1];
            imgArray.push(match);
        });

        //shuffle now if desired
    }
});
```

You may also be able to just write:

```
var imgArray = data.match(/~(.*?)\.jpg/g);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pDD5G/

Answer (score 0):

Se the [docs](http://www.learnjavascript.co.uk/jq/reference/utilities/each.html) of `jQuery.each`.

Javascript does not have references, so, you can't change the values of the elements of an array as you iterate over it.

So, what you have to do is create another array and while iterating, push values into it:

```
var dst = [];
$.each(imgArray, function(i, item) {
   dst.push(item[0].match(/~(.*?)\.jpg/g, "$1")[1]); 
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not just use String `split` instead of regex?

```
for (var i = 0;i < imgArray.length; i++) {
  imgArray[i] = imgArray[i].split('?')[0];
}
```